# unexpected output from signal processing structure module

Tags: verilog, hdl

Undertaking this problem i am getting an unexpected output of X (unknown value) from my Verilog code.

Would appreciate if someone could show me where i am going wrong, code is attached.

> problem

[image]

> module code

```
// Signal processing structure

module sps(in1,clk,rst,out1);

input clk,rst;
input signed [19:0] in1;
output reg signed [19:0] out1;


reg signed [19:0] w,w1;



always @(in1 or w or w1) begin
             w <= in1 + w1;
             out1 <= w + ~w1;
            end

always @(posedge clk) begin
    if(~rst) 
        w <= 0;
    else begin
        w1 <= w;
         end    
end 


        endmodule
```

> testbench code

```
// test sps

module testSps;

reg clk,rst;

reg [19:0] in1;
wire [19:0] out1;


sps sps1(in1,clk,rst,out1);


initial
    begin
    rst = 0;
    clk = 0;
    in1 = 20'b0000000000000000001;
    #5 rst = 1;
    #50 $stop; 
    end

always      
    #5 clk = ~clk;





endmodule
```

Comment: thanks @toolic appreciate the response, could you provide an answer to the question specifying why this is the case?  I would like this in order to understand more what is happening!

Answer (score 0):

Few observations in your design & testbench code.

- You havent initialised the `clk` signal in the testbench. Please add `clk = 0` in the starting of the initial block in your testbench.
- The below `always` block looks self updating loop to me. Because `w` is there in the sensitivity list and also it is being updated in the block.

  ```
  always @(in1 or w or w1) begin
    w <= in1 + w1;
    out1 <= w + ~w1;
  end
  ```
- `w` is driven through multiple always block. A net should be driven only through single always block. You can combine both always blocks to drive `w` as follow. May be you wanted to set `w1` to `0` in the 2nd always block.